# Does One wheelspinning in mud damage my car?

Tags: transmission, automatic-transmission, torque-converter

if one of wheels trap in mud or lifting up on Jack so rotate idle, and another wheel stop to rotate(because differential), is this situation damage torque converter or Automatic transmission?? or Differential will holdup the pressure??!

[a car on jack image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxxuo.jpg)

Comment: I’d say no because this is how the differential works I believe

Answer (score 1):

Not normally, no, but if you suddenly load the transmission i.e. it falls of the jack etc then that sudden shock load can damage components or it hits the wall but not every time...